# Eclipse 3.5 / Statet / R Console not working on Ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, r, ubuntu

I had Eclipse 3.4 working nicely with the R Console over rJava. I want to get Sweave working in Eclipse, but need Eclipse 3.5 / statet 0.8 to do it.

When I try to start the rJava Console the JVM starts, but no feedback comes back to the console in Eclipse.

JVM process below - any help gratefully received.

Thanks, Dave

```
dave     23183 22325  0 Nov20 pts/0    00:00:52 /home/dave/dev/app/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/java -Djava.security.policy=jar:file:/home/dave/dev/app/eclipse-3.5/plugins/de.walware.statet.r.core_0.8.0.b200909221530sw.jar!/localhost.policy -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///home/dave/dev/app/eclipse-3.5/plugins/de.walware.rj.server_0.3.0.b200909221530sw.jar -Xss8192k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/dave/dev/app/eclipse-3.5/plugins/de.walware.rj.server_0.3.0.b200909221530sw.jar:/home/dave/dev/app/eclipse-3.5/plugins/de.walware.rj.data_0.3.0.b200909221530sw.jar:/home/dave/dev/app/eclipse-3.5/plugins/org.eclipse.swt_3.5.1.v3555a.jar:/home/dave/dev/app/eclipse-3.5/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.5.1.v3555a.jar de.walware.rj.server.RMIServerControl start ///rjs-local-1258679148742 -auth=none -plugins=awt,
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it.

I found the Eclipse option which writes stderr to a console, and basically got the trace this guy got, talking about

SEVERE: Unsupported JRI version (API found: 108, required: 109)

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/statet-user/2009-August/000200.html

Basically my rJava installation was out of date. The ubuntu repo gives 0.6.3, but installing the latest 0.8.1 from cran fixed it.